# Problems with Thread.sleep() and mouseMove()

Tags: java, bluej

I want to move my cursor from coordinates (500,500) to new coordinates (1000,200) after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds). I want this event to occur every time the program runs, so that is why I have made a loop. But when I run the program, the cursor only appears to go to coordinates (500,500) and it does not move to coordinates (1000, 200). I need suggestions.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Random;

public class MouseMovers {

    public static  int SECONDS = 5000;
    public static  int MAX_Y =500;
    public static  int MAX_X =500;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Robot rob=new Robot();

        while (true) {
            robot.mouseMove(MAX_X, MAX_Y);
            Thread.sleep(SECONDS);
            rob.mouseMove(1000,200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 5 seconds or 5000 seconds?

Comment: @pamphlet 5, `Thread.sleep` works with milliseconds

Comment: And what's the difference between `rob` and `robot`?

Comment: Is some exception being thrown? Also, why two `Robot` objects?

Comment: @BackSlash, that makes `SECONDS` a very bad name for the variable.

Comment: Five seconds .pls help.

Comment: Why have you made two `Robot` objects?

Comment: Have you tried moving to `1000,200` normally, just to check that you can?

Comment: Have you considered that the moment you move to `1000,200` the loop will iterate and you'll immediately move back to `500,500`?

Comment: @ pamphlet and christopher. it moves only to500,500.As i move the cursor by workig on the mouse,t again goes back to 500,500

Comment: It is hard to tell what "it" is supposed to be when you have two different things. Are you talking about `rob` or `robot`?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title of the question so it describes the problem you're having

Answer (score 4):

Every five seconds your code moves the mouse to (1000,200), and immediately afterwards to (500,500). Add another delay after the second move to make the mouse stay in that place for some time:

```
    while (true) {
        robot.mouseMove(MAX_X, MAX_Y);
        Thread.sleep(SECONDS);
        robot.mouseMove(1000, 200);
        Thread.sleep(SECONDS);
    }
```

BTW: you only need one Robot.

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to use only 1 robot for this work?

Comment: @user3244786 You only need one robot because your two robots are almost the same and you only use them to set the mouse pointer. If you had two lists that would be different, because you could add elements to one list, but not the other, or vice versa, making them different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
    robot.mouseMove(MAX_X, MAX_Y);
    Thread.sleep(SECONDS);
    rob.mouseMove(1000,200);
}
```

It's in a loop. This means robot.mouseMove(MAX_X, MAX_Y) will be executed just after rob.mouseMove(1000,200).

Simply remove the loop. Also note, you only need one instance of the Robot class.

Answer (score 0):

It is useless to have two `Robot` object.

Moreover you do not wait at all between `rob.mouseMove(1000, 200)` and `robot.mouseMove(MAX_X, MAX_Y)`.

Then the correct code should be :

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Random;

public class MouseMovers {

    public static  int MILLISECONDS = 5000;
    public static  int MAX_Y = 500;
    public static  int MAX_X = 500;
    public static  int NEW_MAX_X = 1000;
    public static  int NEW_MAX_Y = 2000;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        while (true) {
            robot.mouseMove(MAX_X, MAX_Y);
            Thread.sleep(MILLISECONDS);
            robot.mouseMove(NEW_MAX_X, NEW_MAX_Y);
            Thread.sleep(MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```